# Prevalence threshold calculations error

Tags: sensitivity-specificity, prevalence

I see on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity#Worked_example) page the formula for calculation of prevalence threshold:

[image]

Given also are following values on that page:

```
Sensitivity or TPR: 66.7%
Specificity or TNR: 91%
```

[image]

With these values, I am getting a prevalence threshold of 27%. However, it is mentioned as 19% on the wiki page.

Where is the error? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to take this up on the Wikipedia page.  It's a real mess and could use some help!

Comment: It will be great if you can put some points in an answer here because most things mentioned on that page are common beliefs.

Comment: I am not claiming that page is wrong: it is just terribly laid out and confusing.  (This calculation you quote does look incorrect, though.)